# Texas weed identification

Tags: identification, weeds

I live in central Texas and have a serious infestation of this weed... I'd like to know what it is so I can buy the right kind of herbicide... I tried searching google images with this, but nothing similar came up...

[image: Central texas weed]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just Lamium amplexicaule, common name Henbit https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamium_amplexicaule, an annual plant - you should be able to pull or dig them out quite easily, but if there are loads of them, you can use something like glyphosate to kill them off, though it's a bit sledgehammer and nut to be honest. Apply when the plants are growing strongly and the ground is damp - glyphosate is not discriminating though, so will kill anything else that's green and growing (excluding woody based plants) if you get it on the foliage.